# Apache Mod_rewrite 301 redirection

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I am new to Apache. I am trying to make a permanent 301 redirect to the following URL via apache mod_rewrite:

http://www.mysite.com/products.php?page=TheForm

to

http://www.mysite.com/the-form/

The problem is that we have a query string in the first URL. How can I deal with this situation as normally I used the following code but the query string cannot be passed to the RewriteRule.

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
     RewriteEngine On
     RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite\.com$ [NC]
     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]

     RewriteRule ^products.php?page=TheForm$ http://www.mysite.com/the-form [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URI-path tested in the rewrite rule does not contain the query. The QUERY_STRING variable should be used.

You may try this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page=TheForm [NC]
RewriteRule ^products\.php  /the-form/? [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, I just tried your code but still it does not work :(

Comment: Please make sure the browser's cache is cleared, it should work. What kind of error do you get?

Comment: just one more question please, will I have to write the RewriteCond for each page that I want to redirect?

Comment: If the target is different, yes. Otherwise you could set an OR condition, like this: `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page=(TheForm|OtherPage1|OtherPage2|...) [NC]`